# R - grab the exact 8 digits number in a string and transform it

Tags: regex, r

I have 2 problems in extracting and transforming data using R.
Here's the dataset:

```
messageID | msg
1111111111 | hey id 18271801, fix it asap
2222222222 | please fix it soon id12901991 and 91222911. dissapointed
3333333333 | wow $300 expensive man, come on
4444444444 | number 2837169119 test
```

The problem is:

I want to grab the number with only 8 digits length. In the dataset above, message id 3333...(300 - 3 digits) and 4444...(2837169119 - 10 digits) should not included. And here's my best shot so far:

```
as.matrix(unlist(apply(df[2],1,function(x){regmatches(x,gregexpr('([0-9]){8}', x))})))
```

.
However, with this line of code, message 444... is included because is contains more than 8 digits number.

Transform the data to another form like this:

```
message_id | customer_ID
1111111111 | 18271801
2222222222 | 12901991
2222222222 | 91222911
```

I don't know how to efficiently transform the data.
The output of `dput(df)`:

```
structure(list(id = c(1111111111, 2222222222, 3333333333, 4444444444
), msg = c("hey id 18271801, fix it asap", "please fix it soon id12901991 and 91222911. dissapointed", 
"wow $300 expensive man, come on", "number 2837169119 test")), .Names = c("id", 
"msg"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks

Comment: use `gregexpr('(?<!\\d)[0-9]{8}(?!\\d)', x, perl=T)` to match the number which has exactly 8 digits.

Comment: thanks @AvinashRaj for quick response! I've just tested your code and it seems work very well. Now I'm struggling to transform the data as described in 2nd problem. Thank you

Comment: could you post the output of `dput(df)` ?

Comment: post it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rebus` to create your regular expression, and `stringr` to extract the matches.

You may need to play with the exact form of the regular expression.  This code works on your examples, but you'll probably need to adapt it for your dataset.

```
library(rebus)
library(stringr)

# Create regex
rx <- negative_lookbehind(DGT) %R%
  dgt(8) %R%  
  negative_lookahead(DGT)
rx
## <regex> (?<!\d)[\d]{8}(?!\d)

# Extract the IDs
extracted_ids <- str_extract_all(df$msg, perl(rx))

# Stuff the IDs into a data frame.
data.frame(
  messageID = rep(
    df$id, 
    vapply(extracted_ids, length, integer(1))
  ),
  extractedID = unlist(extracted_ids, use.names = FALSE)
)
```

Comment: Thanks Richie , your method for my 2nd problem is helpful. I combined Raj's solution with yours in this code:
`extracted_ids <- str_extract_all(df$msg, perl('(?<!\\d)[0-9]{8}(?!\\d)'))`

Comment: If the answer was useful, you can upvote it by clicking the up arrow on the left, and mark the problem as solved by clicking the tick.

Comment: I tried it, but upvote requires 15 reputation. Sorry, I'm newbie here